# Why is this working in Python nosetests when logically it should not

Tags: python, nose

```
class TestUM:

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(will):
        """ Setup Class"""

        will.var = "TEST"

    def setup(this):
        """ Setup """

        print this.var

    def test_number(work):
        """ Method """

        print work.var


    def teardown(orr):
        """ Teardown """

        print orr.var

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(nott):
        """ Teardown Class """

        print nott.var
```

Run it as

> nosetests -v -s test.py

I am not a Python expert but I cannot figure out why the above code works flawlessly using nose. Every print prints "TEST". What exactly is happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In instance methods, the first argument is the instance itself.

In class methods, the first argument is the class itself.

In your case, rather than name that argument `self` or `cls` (the convention), you've named it `this`, `work`, `orr`, and `nott`. But they're all getting the same argument regardless of the *name* of the argument.

You've successfully set the attribute `var` to `"TEST"`, so they all see it correctly.

---

Example functions without the use of classes:

```
def test1(attribute):
    print attribute

def test2(name):
    print name

def test3(cls):
    print cls

def test4(self):
    print self
```

Calling those functions:

```
>>> test1('hello')
hello
>>> test2('hello')
hello
>>> test3('hello')
hello
>>> test4('hello')
hello
```

The name of the argument doesn't matter. All that matters is what the argument is pointing at, which is always the instance or class

Comment: Note that in classmethods it should be named `cls`.

Comment: I am still a bit confused, can you explain like I am five specially this section "But they're all getting the same argument regardless of the name of the argument."